# Feed JAVA_OPTS with multiple parameters

Tags: java, jvm, system-properties

How do I feed a program with multiple parameters as JAVA_OPTS?
When I use something like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="Dx=x1,-Dy=y1"
```

The value that results for x is "x1,-Dy=y1" and the string is not recognised as list.

I didn't find any example with multiple values in a list, so I am wondering about the correct syntax, if it is possible at all!

Comment: Two separate opts should have whitespace between them, not a comma.

Comment: The same way you’d specify them on the command line